# Getting stats about each row and putting them into a new column. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with some values. This is my dataframe:

```
|in|x|y|z|
+--+-+-+-+
| 1|a|a|b|
| 2|a|b|b|
| 3|a|b|c|
| 4|b|b|c|
```

I would like to get number of unique values of each row, and number of values that are not equal to value in column x. The result should look like this:

```
|in | x | y | z | count of not x |unique|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | a | a | b | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | a | b | b | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | a | b | c | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | b | b |nan| 0 | 1 |
```

I could come up with some dirty decisions here. But there must be some elegant way of doing that. My mind is turning around dropduplicates(that does not work on series); turning into array and .unique(); df.iterrows() that I want to evade; and .apply on each row.

Comment: What is the dtype of the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are solutions using apply.

```
df['count of not x'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x[['y','z']] != x['x']).sum(), axis=1)
df['unique'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[['x','y','z']].nunique(), axis=1)
```

A non-apply solution for getting count of not x:

```
df['count of not x'] = (~df[['y','z']].isin(df['x'])).sum(1)
```

Can't think of anything great for unique.  This uses apply, but may be faster, depending on the shape of the data.

```
df['unique'] = df[['x','y','z']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
```

Comment: what about `lambda x: pandas.unique(x).shape[0]`? would that work?