# Python Pandas: count unique values in row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large (16000 rows) dataframe like `df` below. I want to generate a new column which counts the number of unique values in each row without iterating through each row.

So far, I have used the `pd.Series.value_counts` method with `pd.DataFrame.apply()` and `pd.DataFrame.sum()`. But when there are repeating values in the dataframe, this will not get the correct result. How do I count the number of unique values in each row of my dataframe without iterating through it?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5))
>>> df
      0         1         2         3         4
0  0.429437 -0.931365  0.182996  0.627381 -0.166898
1  1.094186  0.080042  0.924192  0.120056  0.667423
2 -0.439858  1.681652 -1.753300  0.390554  0.561703
3  1.579391  1.377110  0.892134  1.704882  0.410462
4 -0.113080 -0.726894  1.904882 -0.800783  0.709755
>>> df['unique'] = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
>>> df
      0         1         2         3         4  unique
0 -0.964615  0.039836 -0.004675  0.067316  0.266369       5
1 -1.582173 -1.329946 -0.597782  1.856062  1.056681       5 
2 -0.566920 -0.107541  0.672243 -1.374591 -0.243655       5
3  0.357264  1.662374 -1.477057  0.629704  0.436156       5
4 -0.318111 -0.472437 -0.222260  0.463293 -0.394258       5
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217124/getting-stats-about-each-row-and-putting-them-into-a-new-column-pandas/25218391#25218391

Comment: Thanks, the `pd.Series.nunique` method seems to work!

Comment: New user here.  @chrisb, why write this as a comment instead of answer?

Comment: @LiamFoley because most likely the question will be tagged as duplicate anyways.